# USPS API Returning 501 NOT IMPLEMENTED

Tags: php, xml, curl, usps

I am attempting to utilize the USPS API to do some address verification/validation.

I'm sending this XML to http://testing.shippingapis.com/ShippingAPITest.dll:

```
<AddressValidateRequest%20USERID="xxxxx"><Address ID="0"><Address1></Address1><Address2>6406 Ivy Lane</Address2><City>Greenbelt</City><State>MD</State><Zip5></Zip5><Zip4></Zip4></Address></AddressValidateRequest>
```

This is the same XML that is shown in their documentation for test requests. However, I always get an HTML (instead of XML) response that is a 501 Not Implmented error. Anyone familiar with this API know what might be going on? I'm using curl (in [php](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php)) to make the request

UPDATE: When I make the request by typing the url into a browser with get params, it seems to work fine, but i get the error mentioned above using php/curl or just curl from the command line.

UPDATE: If I use file_get_contents with the url, I get a 400 bad request error - but if i urlencode, it works great - solution accepted.

Comment: If you have any more problems, Greggory, I'll be happy to assist. I work for a company called SmartyStreets where we validate addresses as well, using official USPS data. The USPS API, while not *bad* per-se, is not necessarily robust for the task, and the USPS' business core is not delivering high-quality APIs. While I may be biased toward our own API (LiveAddress), I might suggest you seek for yourself other free alternatives if you need more performance and something easier to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not familiar with the API, but:

Do you need the `%20` after `AddressValidateRequest`? Does it work when that is replaced by a space?

Also, do you need to use CURL? Could you just use `fopen()` or `file_get_contents()` and then use the GET parameters which you mention work OK?

Comment: The XML shown is identical to what the USPS documentation shows with the %20 only in that one position. However, I have tried replacing it with a space AND replacing all spaces with %20. I'll give the file_get_contents method a shot first chance I get and report back. Thanks!

Comment: Scratch that. file_get_contents works (when I urlencode >.<) This is good enough for me!  Thanks!